Stereo line input & Mono Mixer
I’ve been searching for a module to mix a stereo line input from a laptop with a hot mono input from my Eurorack setup, while also maintaining a proper line output signal.
I love the design of the BMC54 module by Barton Musical Instrument
https://www.bartonmusicalcircuits.com/stereoouts/index.html
but it has only mono inputs.
I’ve created my own version with stereo support.
As I’m relatively new to this hobby, I’d really appreciate your feedback on my design to make sure everything looks correct.
I have a few questions:

Does the overall design look correct?


Can I reduce the value of the R15 resistor below 100k to make the op-amp work with a gain of less than 1? I'm trying to attenuate the mono Eurorack signal, as it's quite hot. Alternatively, would it make more sense to boost the stereo line input by increasing the gain? Or would a passive divider be sufficient?



It looks like you have a schematic bug at C2. Note the wire drawn through the middle of it and the dot junction connecting it to C4.

Also some dot-junction strangeness at R30-U2.pin2, R37-U2.pin6, R29.2.wiper, R10-R29.2, R11-R29.1, R7.2.bottom.  Top tip: when the dot isn't where you'd expect it, something funny is going on.  Often it's unimportant, occasionally it's a disaster.

Your panning circuit has a problem — the combined signal power when panned to the center (both pots at midpoint) is going to be less than half the level at either extreme. This is the result of two effects:

Putting a linear pot at midpoint gives you half the voltage, which is only 1/4 the power.
The source impedance of the pot at midpoint is 1/4 of its total resistance (the two sides are effectively in parallel). A 100k pot will have a source impedance of 25k at midpoint, adding to your 100k resistance going to the mix busses and reducing the signal power even further.

Obviously, you can compensate for this by simply turning up the channel volume after you have it panned where you want it, so this may not be a big deal to you.

Noted. thank you Dave!  Another question - can I reduce the value of the R15 resistor below 100k to make the op-amp work with a gain of less than 1? I'm trying to attenuate the mono Eurorack signal, as it's quite hot. Alternatively, would it make more sense to boost the stereo line input by increasing the gain? Or would a passive divider be sufficient?

I would just go with a passive divider.
